# Sending Query String to publish_action

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've been working with the Graph API recently, and am trying to work with publish_actions.

Now, the current issue is that the page I want to publish, has a query string to identify it.

for example:

```
/me/nodefmradio:comment_on?show=http://example.com/show.php?s=showname',
```

Now, I wish to be able to publish the action for the site with the query string. Is this possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should urlencode the url you're trying to pass as parameter like this :

$url = "/me/nodefmradio:comment_on?show=".urlencode("http://mysite.com/show.php?s=showname");